# .NET MVC 5 DB return old values

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have .NET MVC 5 app. I logged in as Admin in one browser, and as User into another browser. Admin changed Email of User, DB was updated. User was logged out but when I try to log in again I can't do that with old or new email, when I look at break point I see from EF query `SingleOrDefault()` old value of Email.

What's the reason of that? What do I do wrong?

Comment: How is the web app deployed? Are both user and admin pointing to the same server or is it deployed locally on each PC? If it is the later and you are also using a local DB then each PC will have it's own copy of the app completely.

Comment: I launch it  locally (use localhost to test it)